# Top 10 Sold Products with Django queryset order_by "external value"

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, qobject

I am trying to get top 10 sold products from my models.
Models are (they are in diferent apps):

Products:

```
class Product(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ubcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
   product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   product_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

SoldProducts (list of products included after sold):

```
class SoldProduct(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='soldproducts')
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

I have got a list with Product PK and a Sum of sold products with:

```
best_seller_products = SoldProduct.objects.filter(product__in=products, order__in=orders).values(
  'product__pk',).annotate(qty=Sum('quantity')).order_by('-qty')[:6]
```

as result of this queryset:

```
<QuerySet [{'product__pk': 5, 'qty': 22}, {'product__pk': 6, 'qty': 6}]>
```

So I made a two lists. One with the product_pk and other with qty. With the product_pk a got a list off the products with this query:

```
  best_seller_products = products.filter(pk__in=list_best_seller_products_pk)
```

The problem i would like to solve is:
How sort this products list that i got with product_pk with the qty list.
I would mostly prefer to use query instead of creating a "sold" field into Product model.

I really apreciate any help or directions on how to do it!
Thank you very much

Comment: Please share your relevant models.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I eddited the question with my models. Ifo you need any other information just ask me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Product.objecs.filter(soldproduct__order__in=orders).annotate(
    qty=Sum('soldproduct__quantity')
).order_by('-qty')[:6]
```

This will only return `Product`s for which there is at least one `sale` in the `orders` list. We can also include `Product`s with no sales with:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Sum

Product.objecs.annotate(
    qty=Sum('soldproduct__quantity', filter=Q(soldproduct__order__in=orders))
).order_by(F('qty').desc(nulls_last=True))[:6]
```

Comment: You are a genius!!! Thank you very much for you help. It worket perfectly. I was wondering if it is possible to have access through Products to print out the Sum of the 'qty" in each product as each product may have been sold others orders.

Comment: @rmpythoncode: the `Product`s that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.qty` that is the sum of the `quantity`s of the `SoldProduct` items for the given set of `orders`.

Comment: Once again thank you very much. I did not know almost nothing on queries and even with the read i did I couldn't get those to work. But with you explanation I start to understand how things works with django queries. I will practise more and try to help others as you did for me!!! :-)